# Difference between Bootstrap 3 'default' and 'customized' download versions?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have recently started using Bootstrap3 on my projects. 
I would like to understand what is the difference between:
**Bootstrap 3 'default' and 'customized' download versions?**
(Particularly related to how to use/customize LESS in both the cases)

I am attaching the snapshots of the folder structures of the downloaded folders in both the cases.

**Case 1:** Default Download: Has a lot of folders. Q: can i customize LESS variables here and then use all that in my project?

**Case 2:** Customized Download: Has only 3 folders. Contains only the CSS and JS and Fonts. No other folders. And also there is the additional 'bootstrap-theme.css' (under assets/css folder), but it is not in the default version..is it included by default in it?

PS- My reason for asking is so that i can decide when to use the default and when to use the customized version, and do i actually need the customized version?

Thanks.

[image: CASE 1-Bootstrap 3 Default Download Folder structure]

[image: CASE 2-Bootstrap 3 Customized Download Folder structure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you simply download the bootstrap project it gives you all the bells and whistles if you want to set up your grunt server and play with the examples and bower and run tests, etc etc. I am assuming that it grabs it from the repository. The less folder gives you a lot of flexibility, you can read the source code and modify the `variables.less` file. The page on bootstrap's site that lets you customize bootstrap is essentially setting the variables value using the web interface. If you just want to do quick changes use the web interface, otherwise if you want to a lot of manipulation, download the whole thing, take the js and less folder and put it in your project. This way you can just modify the less files and you won't need to go to the site and play with the variables there and download bootstrap every single time you make a change to a variable. Also, downloading the less files enable you to work with other projects that are using less to add more functionality to bootstrap.

Comment: Thanks Amin. Your answer clarifies it for me.
So is it that if i have downloaded the default version, and I make changes to n number of LESS variables, then are those changes automatically included when i attach the bootstrap CSS or do i have to do some compiling after making changes to LESS variables?
Also what about Bootstrap-theme.css not being available in the customized download of BS?